# Yii framework validation rules

Tags: php, validation, yii, frameworks, rules

I am using Yii 1 for my project. I have 5 fields in a form, which must be filled. There's no problem with that - a simple validation rule in model. However, there is one more field, which is not required. But if it is filled, other 5 fields must become not-required. How should I define such validation rules in rules() method in model?

Thank you in advance very much!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, It would help if you would post your rules you speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with scenarios. When you validate your data, check if this field is filled and create new model with specific scenario.

Look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/)

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom validation rule so you can skip scenarios, you will need to:

Stating that:

```
$model->TRIGGERATTR = is the attribute that if informed is going to indicate that the other 5 are required
$model->ATTR1 = one of the five other attributes 
$model->ATTR2 = two of the five other attributes
.
.
. and so on...
```

1. Declare your rule inside your model like : 
   `array('ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3, ATTR4, ATTR5','{NameofRule}Validator'),`
2. Create a custom validation inside your `components/validators/general/{NameofRule}Validator`

   with the following code

`class {NameofRule}Validator extends CValidator
    {
        public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
        {
            if((isset($model->TRIGGERATTR))&&(!is_null($model->TRIGGERATTR))
            {
                if(!isset$model->$attribute||is_null($model->$attribute))
                {
                    $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'Is not Informed and it should be');
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Don´t forget to add your comments and mark as solved ;-)